# Wpf SurfaceListBox Horizontal bounce issue

Tags: wpf, listbox

I am using Wpf SurfaceListBox. I set horizontal layout with:

```
<s:SurfaceListBox>
    <s:SurfaceListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </s:SurfaceListBox.ItemsPanel>
</s:SurfaceListBox>
```

This is ok - displays the items horizontaly.

Issue is that now I lose the 'bounce animation' when trying to scroll left on the start of the list or right on the end of the list.

By 'bounce animation' I mean drag touch animation like 'pull to refresh on phones' that works nicely when vertical layout is set.

This really messes the user experience.

**Is it possible to set horizontal layout without losing this animation?**

Thanks for any information/useful info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SurfaceScrollViewer.Elasticity property

It is the type of Vector

Set the Property X offset from 0 to 0.2

like below code

```
<s:SurfaceListBox s:SurfaceScrollViewer.Elasticity="0.2,0.4">
```